# What is the power efficient way to keep offline data in sync with the server without GCM?

Tags: android, offline-caching

I'm building an Android client for an Internet discussion board: the app downloads the discussions from the server and displays them using the native Android UI.  It was quite easy to build the basics such as getting and displaying the content, and posting the replies back to the server.

Now I want to bring it to the next level: the app should store all the data locally on the device and sync it with the server periodically, getting the recent changes and updating the local DB.  I don't want it to check for the changes on demand; the periodic updates are better because this allows some nice features like subscribing to the updates.

Unfortunately the server is not GCM-compliant (and it will never be), it is a good old simple web server so I have to implement the sync myself.

I've found [a comment to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356469/1380150) where it's said that a timer-based check is a bad idea because the device will have to wake up and connect to the Internet.  It would be much better to catch when the device begins its own data sync, but its there a way to handle this without a perioic check?

I've looked over many discussions on this issue; most of them discuss the ContentProviders, protocols, services like GCM/C2DM and so on.  I've found nothing about the power efficiency.

So how to do the sync properly so my app wouldn't drain the battery?

Comment: it would be better if you use c2dm now known as GCM as the server can push updates if available that would be power efficient than polling :)

Comment: GCM is great but it requires the server to do some work.  In my case, this is hardly possible (I already have the server and I cannot make it GcM-compliant).  I'll update the original post to mark this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be better if you use GCM as the server can push updates if available that would be power efficient than polling as network will only be used when updates are available its far better than timely polling as it will check and wake the phone just to check for updates

Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

but as you cant get with GCM you will have to go for polling itself you can use it in a power efficiant way by using alarm manager and inexact repeating

i think that is the best power efficient way to poll periodically

giving a sample code

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Restart service every 30 sec
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30 ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        //
        // Fetch every 30 seconds
        // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

        // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        // REPEAT_TIME, pending);
    }
}
```

(There is a [more detailed explanation that includes the necessary manifest items](http://www.hascode.com/2011/11/managing-background-tasks-on-android-using-the-alarm-manager/).)

Comment: Thanks for the code; this looks to be an answer but I need to try implementing this.  However, would it be more power-efficient to pass RTC instead of RTC_WAKEUP?  My service would sleep until the device wakes up due to some other reason (some other sync wakes it up for example).

Comment: it depends on your use if you use rtc phone wont trigger alarm( triger the intent in the above code) if its sleeping

Comment: But will it trigger it later when it wakes up due to some other reason?  If yes then it's fine.

Comment: yap it will go on when the device wakes up next ;)

Comment: public static final int RTC

Since: API Level 1
Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC). This alarm does not wake the device up; if it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device wakes up.

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
public static final int RTC_WAKEUP

Since: API Level 1
Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)

Comment: I've found a [more detailed explanation of the approach that you suggested](http://www.hascode.com/2011/11/managing-background-tasks-on-android-using-the-alarm-manager/); did you mean something like that?  Anyway this seems to be working.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: yap that's something similar ;) and of course they are using similar code :)

Answer (score 0):

you can build a small server side app that will do the periodic polling and utilize GCM to notify the Android client for any updates.

ofcourse that you'll have other problems, such as the need for polling for each one of your users.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be with GCM, but as you said, that's not possible for you. In such a case, this is what I recommend:

1. Update over WiFi if possible. This way you're likely to get the data transfer done more quickly, and hence reduce the amount of time required for the device's radios to be active.
2. Bunch transfers together. Don't transfer say 1 file, and then wait for a bit to do another transfer. Instead, transfer right after the other. This reduces the amount of time the radios need to be active for, and hence conserves battery life
3. Update when charging, and update more. If the device is charging, you can keep the network connection alive for longer without killing the battery. So you could sync maybe 3 days of data instead of 24 hours of data while on charging, and save battery for when the user wants that 2 days of data that would have not been synced normally.

You could also watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM) session from IO 2012 on efficiency when using networks.